# How to create fields within a loop for a model?

Tags: django, django-models

In my project, I want to create some models which store statistic data, in these models, there would be one or two fields for each hour, that's to say, there are at least 24 or 48 fields in these models.

In normal way, I have to write 24 or 48 fields (with same attribute, different field names) for each model, it's not so elegant and efficient. For example:

```
class Stats(models.Model)
    cnt_0 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ...
    cnt_23 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Is it possible to create these fields within a loop or any other ways to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is a static number of fields, it is possible to create the fields in a more DRY way:

```
class Stats(models.Model):
    pass

for i in range(24):
    Stats.add_to_class('cnt_%s' % i, models.IntegerField(default=0)
for i in range(24, 48):
    Stats.add_to_class('cnt_%s' % i, models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
```

This method is essentially the same as explicitly defining the field as a class attribute. The main difference is that the `class_prepared` signal is sent before these fields are added to the class.

For a dynamic number of fields, go with Rohan's suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Its not possible to create fields that way. The better way would be to create another model to hold `(name,value)` of such attributes.

Sample code

```
class Stats(models.Model)
    #your fields

class Attributes(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField()
    value = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    stats = models.ForeignKey(Stats)
```

You can add as many as attributes needed for the stats and have other constraints as per your requirements.

Comment: @knbk provides a better solution for my real problem, anyway your answer gives a good choice for future reference, it's perfect for the dynamic fields situation. Thanks a lot.